# asp.net mvc - reusing controller values among actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a main Landing page (initial page) in which i need to make a service call. the values of that model will help me determine to show another page/action or not.

lets pick a scenario, Review date if its in past, i will show a new page/action "ReviewData" that is in the same controller .cs class only. If that date is in future, I will show another page/action "Summary" which is also using the same .cs controller class.

Now, if i go to "ReviewData", i need the same service call data that i made above earlier. I don't want to make this service call every now and then, as all these attempts its same value. how do i avoid this and possibly can reuse the data/model values from the first service call?

Comment: Could you please show code example

Comment: Caching models at the controller isn't how MVC was designed.  It was instead designed with ability to [Improve Performance with Output Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs).

Comment: But i still feel that making the same service call again to get the same data more than once in an app even though at two different actions, would not be worth, isnt it? I am having the two actions under the same controller class. One action yielding the service response data, why it cant be or how it can be reused in the another action without making the same service call? is that something be acheived using parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some caching stratergies here is simple cache helper class

```
using System.Runtime.Caching;  

public class cacheservice: ICacheservice
{
    public T GetOrSet<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class
    {
        T item = MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) as T;
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = getItemCallback();
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, item, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10));
        }
        return item;
    }
}

interface ICacheService
{
    T GetOrSet<T>(string cacheKey, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class;
}
```

Usage:

```
cacheservice.GetOrSet("CACHEKEY", (delegate method if cache is empty));
```

Cache provider will check if there's anything by the name of "CACHEKEY" in the cache, and if there's not, it will call a delegate method to fetch data and store it in cache.

**Example:**

```
var Data=cacheService.GetOrSet("CACHEKEY", ()=>SomeRepository.GetData())
```

You can customize according to your needs as well

Comment: my apologies. and i may be, beginner to this topic, but being a long time dev on asp.net classic world, i am still not convinced with the options laid out. why would a MVC framework not have abilities like my scenario? or am i not still getting the basics on what can be achieved on MVC? If i need to avoid multiple web service calls and utilize the values on follow up needs, what are other options apart from session, caching (is this another store more or less like session in my case). would you elaborate or help me on some links/sources for these topics in particular, on the asp.net MVC?

Comment: Ohh no issue i can understand your concern but what comes to picture when we create a application using MVC is performance and your  scenario is similar to the performance concern right? If you find how to improve performance of MVC application there are many of the article around the world but there is one common thing you will find is **CACHING** though MVC  provide inbuilt caching using `OutputCache` but it'll not fit with your requirement so you need to worked on some Caching strategies

Comment: here is some useful links [1](http://www.trigent.com/blog/so-you-want-to-improve-performance-of-asp-net-mvc4-application/), [2](https://dzone.com/articles/how-improve-performances) , [3](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/04/17/how-to-improve-the-performances-of-aspnet-mvc-web-applications/), [4](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41930/How-To-Improve-the-Performance-of-ASP-NET-MVC-Web) again one point is common across all the links are **Caching** i hope you'll satisfy with and implement some caching strategies for your application ;-)

Comment: yes. this really helped me. sorry for late response though. i consider these as a solution to my problem need. Anyone who is looking at this topic and the answer, please look for the links and topics in the comment section.

Answer (score -1):

The answer of the question : 
 -  Can reuse the data/model values from the first service call?
- Yes. 
  You can achieve this using Tempdata: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.aspx